# Prove that the equation has no integer solutions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, diophantine-equations

Prove that for infinitely many integers  $n>2$ equation
$a^n-(a-2)^n=b^{n-1}$ 
has no integer solutions for $a,b$.
Edit: I would appreciate any hints. They may concern other nonlinear diophantine equations for n>... as I think I wouldn't be able to do even another example and I guess I may not be the only one having these difficulties

Comment: Can someone explain why it got downvoted?

Comment: Why do you downvote?

Comment: A downvote means (official definition on this site) "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." Where's your research? What's your question? Imperatives like "prove", "show", "explain" aren't popular, here.

Comment: @Professor Vector I got a Diophantine exercise list with equations of exponents 2,3,4 and 5. Then there is this one, that I have no idea how to solve

Comment: @user509482 Just a curiosity. What kind of school do you attend? I ask because I am a math graduate here in Italy and I never had such assignments...

Comment: @Raffaele It's for non-obligatory math class in a high school in Berlin

Comment: Folks, please stop voting this down. Diophantine equations are hard, and OP just wants a hint.

Comment: Obligatory class or no, it's utter nonsense to give such problems to people without the necessary background. Where can I downvote the professor?

Comment: @user509482 Not obligatory means: *skip it*. Because asking here and getting a solution that is not your work is not fair :) furthermore it's useless...

Comment: Could you give some hints though? I think that they may be helpful not only for me

Comment: @ProfessorVector 1^4-(1-2)^4=1-1=0 and (-1)^(3)=-1

Comment: @ProfessorVector If I understood correctly your comment I think it is not true

Comment: Oops, I meant to write: if $n$ is even, $a=1$ and $b=0$ is a solution.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Now I see. I've naively changed when translating the part about n>2. Originally it wasn't for ALL but for INFINITELY MANY.

Comment: @ProfessorVector do you think you can help me with this one?

Comment: Then, you should edit your question.

Comment: @ProfessorVector is it ok now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation doesn't have integer solutions, if $n$ is an odd prime: because of the theorem of Fermat, we have $x^{n-1}=1\pmod n$, for $x\neq0\pmod n$, so that always $x^n=x\pmod n$. That means $a^n-(a-2)^n=a-(a-2)=2\pmod n$. But $b^{n-1}\pmod n$ is $0$ if $n$ divides $b$, and $1$ otherwise, so the equation can't be satisfied.

Comment: b^(n-1)(mod n) is 0 when b (mod n)=1 and 1 when b (mod n) doesn't equal 1?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I've edited it.

Comment: b^(n-1)(mod n) is 0 when b (mod n)=0 and 1 when b (mod n) doesn't equal, am I right?